# How to use multiprocessing for sequential memory hungry tasks?

Tags: python, memory-management, multiprocessing

I am trying to execute a series of tasks that use a lot of memory because of the objects sizes. Basically here are the steps :

```
a = building_function()
saving_to_disk(a)
b = building_function(a)
saving_to_disk(b)
c = building_function(b)
saving_to_disk(c)
d = building_function(b, c)
saving_to_disk(d)
```

When b is built, I do not need "a" anymore, but it is still in memory.
Same thing for b and c when d is built.
I've tried "del a" but it doesn't work.

So here's the MWE of what I'm thinking of trying. Before I waste lots of time implementing it, is that the right approach ?

```
                    def loadData():
                        return 'data'

                    def building_function(x, y, res_queue):
                        result = "using " + x + " to build " + y
                        res_queue.put(result)

                    def saving_to_disk(res_queue):
                        res = res_queue.get()
                        while res != 'END':
                            print(res + " (saved)")
                            res = res_queue.get()

                    res_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

                    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=saving_to_disk, args=[res_queue])
                    data = loadData()
                    p.start()
                    building_function(data, 'a', res_queue)
                    building_function('a', 'b', res_queue)
                    building_function('b', 'c', res_queue)
                    building_function('b and c', 'd', res_queue)
                    res_queue.put("END")
                    p.join()
```

Comment: You'd like to have a different process to write your result to disk and then remove from memory, is that correct ?

Comment: Yep, I don't really need the multiprocess, only the memory management that it brings.
Never did any multi proc/thread so I really don't know what I'm doing here ^^

Comment: If it's only for I/O operations I would suggest using a threading API. Multithreading is mostly useless in Python because of the GIL except for I/O bound operations. The issue you'd face with processes is that sharing memory is tedious at best so you'd end up duplicating the data and pickling it which would increase your memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see what "memory management" creating processes brings to what you are trying to accomplish. What you want to do is set a reference to an instance that uses a lot of memory to `None` when you no longer need it so that it can be garbage collected and call `gc.collect()` to force the immediate garbage collection (although garbage collection should occur automatically as necessary):

```py
import gc

def loadData():
    return 'data'

def building_function(x):
    # Compute result from x:
    ...
    return result

def saving_to_disk(result):
    print(result + " (saved)")

data = loadData()
a = building_function(data)
saving_to_disk(a)
# We don't need data any more:
data = None
gc.collect()

b = building_function(a)
saving_to_disk(b)
# We don't need a any more:
a = None
gc.collect()

c = building_function(b)
# We don't need b any more:
b = None
gc.collect()
saving_to_disk(c)
```

Comment: Wow I just tested and it seems to work (to be confirmed with full testing). I don't understand why though...
why does "del a gc.collect()" not free any memory while "a = None gc.collect()" seems to do ?
Thanks

Comment: They should both work the same as far as resulting in garbage collecting what `a` had originally referenced. With `del`, however, variable `a` would no longer exist at all instead of referencing a different object, i.e. `None`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693946).

Comment: Well, worked on my local machine, I could see the memory freed with htop. Does NOT work on my AWS server... Have to make a separate bash process for each step I couldn't find a better way. So annoying.

Answer (score 0):

gc.collect() really didn't work for me so I decided to cut my process into several functions that I call from a bash file using separate commands.
In the end it's simpler and more straightforward